# attributeGroup needs to appear after an enumeration in XSD

Tags: xsd, xml-validation

XML standards say that an attributeGroup needs to appear after an enumeration in a restriction. Is this true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, depends on what you are after.

If you have an restriction with `<enumeration>` and `<attributeGroup>` elements, then out of these two `<enumeration>` needs to appear first. But besides `<restriction>` `<attributeGroup>` elements can appear also as child of `<attributeGroup>` (nested groups), `<complexType>`, `<extension>`, `<redefine>` or `<schema>` (global groups).